# Area of triangle given two sides and altitude

Tags: geometry

> A triangles altitude to the $15$in sides measures $8$in, find the area.

I drew the triangle and once I try to figure out the base using Pythagorean theorem I get $\sqrt {161}$, how do I solve the problem?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say

Comment: Well the title is area of polygons and circles but for some reason it wasn't allowing me to post it because the title exist already, anyway I've drew a triangle and both the sides are 15 and the altitude is 8 so once I've tried to use pythagorean theorem to find the missing side I get radical 121

Comment: Did [a quick sketch](http://imgur.com/a/Akacd) on MS paint. Which is correct, the green or the red?

Comment: @EdithMendoza - Please consider adding a diagram as the question is not clear from what you have written.

Comment: @suomynonA the green one matches how I have it because the question says the 15in sides but it doesn't say the base is 15 on the sides so when I use pythagorean theorem to solve for the missing side I end up with radical 121

Comment: I posted an answer based on what I got from you, but if the correct answer is $\sqrt {121}$ that's just $11$.

Comment: @suomynonA sorry it's not 121 it's 161

Answer (score 2):

Based on OP's interpretation [(green)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUGYc.jpg)

The area of half of the base would be $\sqrt{15^2-8^2}=\sqrt{161}$ Multiply by the height, $8$, to get $8\sqrt{161}$

Comment: That's what I got but it seems wrong to me

Comment: The area is $8\sqrt{161}$ if your interpretation is correct